# What does the percent (%) operator do on strings?

Tags: python, string-formatting

I am currently working on a "Learn Python" course, and I came across this snippet:

```
f.write("This is line %d\r\n" % (i+1))
```

The thing is, I'm not entirely sure what "%d\r\n" and "%" are doing in the string?

Could someone tell me what they're doing, or point me in the right direction to some resources?

Thank you.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: This is string-formatting taking place in a string that contains a couple escaped characters. `\r` is the carriage return character, `\n` is the newline character. `%d` is string-formatting an integer, which you supply via `% (i+1)`.

Comment: If the course does not explain the code it uses, consider finding a better course

Comment: +1 on what DeepSpace said, and from that line alone I can determine this is an older course. Try finding a more recent one